# Recursively search for files of a given name, and find instances of a particular phrase AND display the path to that file

Tags: bash, file, shell, grep, msys

I have a bunch of folders and subfolders. Each one contains, amongst other things,  a text file called `index.yml` with useful data. I want to search through all of the different `index.yml` files to find instances of a search string. I must be able to see a few lines of context and the directory of the `index.yml` file that was found.

This almost works, but it doesn't give me the filename:

```
cat `find . -name 'index.yml'`| grep -i -C4 mySearchString
```

How can I do this and get the filename?

I am stuck on Windows with using msys. Note I don't seem to have full GNU grep, so I can't run `grep --exclude` or `grep -R` as suggested in other SO questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this:

```
find -name "index.yml" -exec grep -i -H -C4 pattern {} \;
```

note: not actually tested under msys.

Comment: This is the right answer for a normal unix like system.  I couldn't get something like this, or an xargs variety to work on cygwin

Comment: Great! Thanks. As soon as SO lets me.. i will accept this answer. Seems to be some time limit.

Comment: @AndyL `{}` is replaced with a filename (or directory name) find found. `\;` denotes the end of the arguments for exec. the slash is to escape the semicolon from the shell. sometimes it is also necessary to escape the `{}`.

Comment: That's a "backslash" not a "slash".

Comment: on osx had to specify a path to search, `find . -name "index.yml" -exec grep -i -H -C4 pattern {} \;`

Answer (score 0):

One possibility (I don't know what msys accepts exactly):

```
 find . -name index.yml -exec grep -i -C4 mySearchString /dev/null {} +
```

The `/dev/null` serves to ensure there are at least two pathnames so that the pathname is printed with each match. The `-H` option to grep has a similar effect.

The `-exec`...`+` construct in `find` causes multiple pathnames to be passed to a single instance of the command. If it is not implemented, you'll have to use `-exec`...`\;`.