# Linux terminal: Recursive search for string only in files w given file extension; display file name and absolute path

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, grep

I'm new to Linux terminal; using Ubuntu Peppermint 5.

I want to recursively search all directories for a given text string (eg 'mystring'), in all files which have a given file extension (eg. '*.doc') in the file name; and then display a list of the file names and absolute file paths of all matches. I don't need to see any lines of content.

This must be a common problem. I'm hoping to find a solution which does the search quickly and efficiently, and is also simple to remember and type into the terminal.

I've tried using 'cat', 'grep', 'find', and 'locate' with various options, and piped together in different combinations, but I haven't found a way to do the above.

Something similar was discussed on:
[How to show grep result with complete path or file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875380/how-to-show-grep-result-with-complete-path-or-file-name)

and:
[Recursively search for files of a given name, and find instances of a particular phrase AND display the path to that file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538987/recursively-search-for-files-of-a-given-name-and-find-instances-of-a-particular)

but I can't figure a way to adapt these to do the above, and would be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [`grep`](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) manual, you can do this using the `--include` option (combined with the `-l` option if you want only the name — I usually use `-n` to show line numbers):

> **`--include=`*glob***
>
> Search only files whose name matches *glob*, using wildcard matching as described under `--exclude`.
>
> **`-l`**
>
> **`--files-with-matches`**
>
> Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which output would normally have been printed. The scanning of each file stops on the first match. (`-l` is specified by POSIX.)

A suitable *glob* would be "*.doc" (ensure that it is quoted, to allow the shell to pass it *to* `grep`).

GNU grep also has a *recursive* option `-r` (not in [POSIX grep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/grep.html)).  Together with the globbing, you can search a directory-tree of ".doc" files like this:

```
grep -r -l --include="*.doc" "mystring" .
```

If you wanted to make this portable, then [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html) is the place to start.  But using `grep`'s *extension* makes searches much faster, and is available on any Linux platform.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and link to the grep manual. I'm afraid I still don't understand how to construct a working script from your response. Please could you give an example based on my original question. Many thanks.

Comment: (and @Klaus): Thanks both for your help and for recent edits & examples. I understand grep a little better from the manual now and see how both your methods are meant to work; but neither of them seems to work on my system (Samsung N140 Netbook running LXTerminal / Ubuntu Peppermint 5 ) I just get an unblinking white square cursor, and no output. Not sure if this indicates a problem with my hardware, or software... or is this meant to happen, and did I miss something in the manual ?

Comment: The sample line that I gave works here (and should work on "any" Linux, since it uses GNU grep).  Perhaps you overlooked the "." (dot) at the end, which indicates the current directory.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. The command was typed correctly. I've made a text file in my home/user folder called "text.txt" containing the single word "spam". When I navigate to this folder, the command ls confirms that the test file is present, but it doesn't seem to be detected by: grep -r -l --include= "*.txt" "spam" .  The system just freezes with an unblinking white cursor, and doesn't seem to exit unless I press ^c. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: In your comment, there is a space after `--include`.  If you have that in the actual command, it will not use `"*.txt"` as the option value, but as the literal string to search for, and look in something called `spam` (probably not what was intended).

Comment: Apologies: this was a typo in my posting. The contents of test.txt are displayed when I use cat test.txt, so I don't think it is a permissions issue. grep -r -I "spam" and your example both return paths to other files (but not test.txt), then freeze on my Samsung netbook running Peppermint 5 with LXTerminal; yet  your solution works fine on another identical Samsung netbook running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Terminal. Very strange. I'm not familiar with the differences between different Linux distros, but could this possibly be due to a bug or missing file in my Peppermint 5 / LXTerminal install ?

Comment: That would be unusual (not impossible).  You could have some *data* differences in the files searched, which when typing their contents to the terminal would stop output (you might consider redirecting the output of the grep to a file to check that).

Comment: `grep -r -l --include="*.txt" "spam" . > results.txt` yielded the correct result on the Peppermint 5 netbook after 45 min! In contrast, the Ubuntu 12.04 netbook responded almost immediately. Not sure why such a difference (?HDD utilisation, ?available RAM), but it seems I just needed more patience! Many thanks for your advice and support.

Answer (score 2):

> find . -name '*.doc' -exec grep -l 'mystring' {} \; -print

How it works:

find searches recursively from the given path `.`

for all files which name is `'*.doc'`

`-exec grep` execute grep on files found

suppress output from grep `-l`

and search inside the files for `'mystring'`

The expression for grep ends with the `{} \;`

and `-print` print out all names where grep founds `mystring`.

EDIT: 
To get only results from the current directory without recursion you can add:
`-maxdepth 0` to find.

Comment: 1) Thanks for explaining how the command works - very helpful. Unfortunately, when I run this script on my system, LX Terminal gives me a static white square cursor and seems to freeze. Not sure why this is.

Comment: ( I have copied your script exactly) - any suggestions?  2) Is it possible to modify this script so it only searches the current working directory - i.e. no recursion ?

Comment: @Dave: You should start reading the man pages! The information you requested is in there :-) I edited my answer for the "no recursion" information.